# Fused activation functions of conv ops should be NONE but they are RELU6

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to convert a frozen mobilenet_v1 graph to tflite. I'm interested in the conversion process and not just the quantized tflite model, so I'm comparing my converted model to one already made by tensorflow. The difference between them is that my conv2d nodes have a relu6 activation function while the correct model's conv2d nodes don't have any activation function. How should I go about fixing this problem?

I should also mention that I'm converting to a fully quantized tflite model by using tensorflow's quantization-aware training and activating the quantization flags upon conversion to tflite.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried searching through the source code to see where the activation function is set but with no luck